# How can i disable Jzoom in PS 1.7?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7, jqzoom

I can disable option Jzoom, on Prestashop 1.7. I can´t disable.

My products store is based on Prestashop.

https://elgrifo.com/tienda/es/

I changed products.tpl and product-cover-thumbnails.tpl without success.

Can you help me?

Prestashop 1.7. I searched zoom modules in my system, but i don´t have modules in this way i think.

Disable Jzoom query in Prestashop 1.7

Answer (score 0):

just remove the A tag who call the zoom modal (i guees in product-cover-thumbnails.tpl):

```
<a class="expander" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#product-modal"><span><i class="fa fa-expand" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></a>
```

In case you cannot find the tag, had this JS snippet to desactivate the click on picture :

```
$('.expander').click(function(e){return false;});
```

Comment: okay, i found this tag on your product page, so my advice is to search recursvly in your theme folder, search for class="expander"

Comment: i searched on www folder (main folder) without results. I used grep on linux and search by content on Windows 10.

Comment: you use an commercial template (warehouse from iqit) who is different from the native template, it s why you can not find the tag, so i edit my post to desactivate the click on pic

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your answers. Unfortunately, I am a regular user, I do not have much knowledge.
Where can I find JS Snippet?

Comment: Hi, i found it. There is an option in Iqit Theme Editor > Content/Pages > Product lists/Carousels > Second image on hover - Desactivated

Answer (score 0):

I was able to change it through the theme editor.

Comment: Don't add thanks as answer. But, please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation. But add some more context to your answer e.g. for the solution you have had found.